# How to create an Excel file in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need to write a VB class that will create an Excel file and pass into this file a list of variables.

Afterwards I need to be able to convert the program to a .dll so that it can be called by a program.

Its been a while since I have written any code so thought that VB would be a good refresher but all the example I can find all start from within Excel. I need the call to create the file to be from outside of Excel.

Comment: Check this out: http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_create_file.htm

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look at the OpenXML SDK For Microsoft Office. Unlike many of the examples you'll find that use `Microsoft.Office.Interop`, this approach does not require Microsoft Office to be installed.

- [OpenXML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)
- [OpenXML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

There is a complete how-to on MSDN for [generating Excel workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: I would further recommend using a wrapper around the raw OpenXML SDK, e.g. [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/).